# Pass value for asp-rout-data using jQuery code

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to pass value of input tag with class "count"; I want to pass the value to asp-rout-count property in the a tag using jQuery or js. I have tried to do that with this code but I could not.

html markup:

```
<div class="qty col-4" style="float:left">
    <h5>العدد &nbsp;</h5>
    <span class="plus bg-info">+</span>
    <input type="number" class="count" value="1" max="10">
    <span class="minus bg-info">-</span><br /><br />
    @if (Model.BuyingPrice <= currentUser.Balance)
    {
        <a asp-action="Buy" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" asp-route-count="r_id" class="btn btn-outline-info col-12">إشتري الان</a>
    }

    @if (Model.BuyingPrice > currentUser.Balance)
    {
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info col-12" href="#" onClick="alert('رصيدك الحالي غير كافي')">إشتري الان</a>
    }
</div>
```

and jQuery part:

```
<script>
    var r_id = getIdFromURL();

    function getIdFromURL() {
        var id = $(".count").val();
        return id;
</script>
```

Comment: you miss closing bracket `}` of  your `getIdFromURL()` function

Comment: @FrustratedDeveloper thanks ..but it is stilling not work